# Tomcat worker not working

Tags: apache, tomcat

This is on CentOS 7 system, apache 2.4.6, java jdk1.8.0_77, tomcat 7

http://www.example.com:8080/manager/html shows tomcat application manager and my_application running.

httpd.conf includes:

```
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
```

in conf.d folder, the file gau.conf contains:

```
LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
JkWorkersFile /etc/httpd/conf/workers.properties
JkShmFile     /var/log/httpd/mod_jk.shm
JkLogFile     /var/log/httpd/mod_jk_log
JkLogLevel    info
JkOptions +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat -ForwardDirectories
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^/servlet.gupld(.*)$ /path_to_detect/servlet.gupld [PT,QSA,L]
JkMount /path_to_detect worker1
JkMount /path_to_detect/* worker1
```

workers.properties file is:

```
worker.list=worker1
worker.worker1.type=ajp13
worker.worker1.host=localhost
worker.worker1.port=8009
worker.worker1.lbfactor=1
```

server.xml contains:

```
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" address="0.0.0.0" />
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

The js file can be accessed on tomcat port:

http://www.example.com:8080/path_to_detect/file.js

I expect this file to be accessed on 80 port (but served by tomcat):

http://www.example.com/path_to_detect/file.js

But a 404 Not Found error is shown.

java -version:

```
java version "1.8.0_77"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_77-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.77-b03, mixed mode)
```

nmap -6 ::1 -p 8009:

```
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-04-10 14:20 UTC
Nmap scan report for localhost.localdomain (::1)
Host is up (-1100s latency).
PORT     STATE SERVICE
8009/tcp open  ajp13
```

log files are not showing any error.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

1. change JkLogLevel from "info" to "debug" and restart apache,
2. try to access using the worker and check mod_jk_log
3. mod_jk_log shows "jk_translate::mod_jk.c (3855): missing uri map for"
4. add "JkMountCopy all" in my conf file (gau.conf)
5. restart.

Thanks.